# Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous at $ x=a$, with $f(a)<g(a)$. Prove that there exists a neighborhood $I$ of a such that $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x \in I$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous at $x=a$, with $f(a)< g(a)$. Prove that there exists a neighborhood $I$ of $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)< g(x)$ for all $x \in I$.

It might be helpful to use the theorem that states: If $\lim_{ x\to a} f(x)=L$, $L$ is not $0$, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>L/2>0$ for 0$ < |x-a| < \delta$.

Answer (score 1):

You have that $g(a)-f(a)>0$. Look at the function $g-f$. Then $g-f\to (g-f)(a)>0$ when $x\to a$, and $g-f$ is continuous at $x=a$. What does this tell you? Use that proposition you state. More precisely, it states:

> **PROP** Let $f$ be continuous at $x=a$, and $f(a)>0$. Then there exists a nbhd $N$ of $a$ such that $f>0$ over $N$.

Comment: [Edit makes comment old hat, thanks]

Answer (score 1):

Hints: take

$$\epsilon:=\frac{g(a)-f(a)}{3}\;,\;\;h(x):=f(x)-g(x)$$

Since $\,h\,$ is continuous at $\,x=a\,$ (why?) there exists $\,\delta>0\,$ s.t.

$$|h(x)-h(a)|<\epsilon\iff |f(x)-g(x)-(f(a)-g(a))|<\epsilon\ldots$$